# The website menu stopped working after Chrome update 29.0.1547.66 m

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The link for the top level menu "CONTACT" on my website [www.dubaidesigndistrict.com](http://www.dubaidesigndistrict.com) stopped working after the google chrome update.

it is working fine with ie and Chrome v28 but not with v 29.

Kindly help with a solution.

```
<div id="smoothcontainer" class="hidden-phone ddsmoothmenu">
<ul>
<li class="m1" ><a href="index.php" data-scrolloffset="20"   >DISTRICT</a></li>
<li class="m2"><a href="design.php"  >DESIGN</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="d3-sectors.php" style="color:#ff9e00" >d3 SECTORS</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="m3"><a href="dubai.php"  >DUBAI</a> </li>
<li class="m4"><a href="press-release.php" >MEDIA</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="press-release.php"   >NEWS RELEASES</a></li>
<li><a href="industry-quotes.php"   >INDUSTRY QUOTES</a></li>
<li><a href="media-coverage.php"   >MEDIA COVERAGE</a></li>
<li><a href="industry-insights-1.php"   >INDUSTRY INSIGHTS</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="m5"><a href="contact.php"   >CONTACT</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="d3-team.php"   >LEADERSHIP</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working

Comment: Please take a look in the developer console (press F12), there are some *invalid CSS* warnings.

Comment: @ Ollie on the website if you click on the link contact it should take to the contact us page before it was working fine but after the chrome update it stopped working and it is fine with ie and older version of chrome.

Comment: Gosh I really hate that Chrome! Im not surprised at all.. PS: probably a bug in Chrome, as always :P